# What is killing my MacBook Pro battery?

Tags: macos, battery, macbook-pro, battery-life

My 2013 MBPr has suddenly been draining its battery when it isn't plugged in and the lid is closed. Sometimes down it hits 1 or 0 percent to cause a deep sleep. According to the advanced battery menu, the condition is normal, so I don't think its the age of the battery.

Are there logs or other utilities I can use to investigate?

Comment: Which version of macOS are you running?

Comment: @Spiff the latest High Sierra

Comment: Check in the activity monitor to see what is using the most of the CPU and battery for the longest time.